# C# Getting Attribute Value from HtmlElement

Tags: c#, getattribute, htmlelements

I am getting an HtmlElement from a click.

```
HtmlElement element = WebBrowser.Document.GetElementFromPoint(e.ClientMousePosition);
```

This neatly returns an

- HtmlElement

with Id (`loginUserName`), OuterHTML (`<input class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-isolate-scope ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" id="loginUserName" required="" type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-enter="ok()" ng-model="user.username" surec-focus="true">`) etc.

When I try to get the value of the "class" attribute with ...

```
string classNameValue = element.GetAttribute("class");
```

... it returns an empty string.

Any idea why the method is unable to retrieve the attribute value?

Bizarre part is that ...

```
string elementId = element.GetAttribute("id");
```

...does return a value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HTMLAgilityPack, tt's normal, you get the "attribute" object, which is composed of a name and a value.

Just do this :

```
string classNameValue = element.GetAttribute("class").Value;
```

Comment: Error CS1061 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no accessible extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @RicoStrydom My project use HTMLAgilityPack, try with this nugget package.